# Proving a mapping from a higher dimension to a lower dimension is continuous?

Tags: real-analysis

How does one show a mapping is continuous from a higher dimension to a lower dimension. For example:

Let f : $\mathbb{R}^2$ $\rightarrow$ $\mathbb{R}$, (x,y) $\rightarrow$ x. How would you show this is continuous.

My attempt was to use the definition of continuous:
That is: f is continuous at $x_0 \in$ its domain if and only if for every $\epsilon$ > 0, there exists a $\delta$ > 0 such that for all x $\in$ its domain A, d(x,$x_0$) < $\delta$ implies $\gamma$(f(x),f($x_0$)) < 0.

So set y = $y_0$ and then the proof should be vascuous. However, I feel that there is something wrong with this approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $z_0=(x_0,y_0)$ be an arbitrary point in the domain. Let $\epsilon>0$.
We need to exhibit $\delta>0$ such that for all $z=(x,y)$ with $d(z,z_0)<\delta$ we have $d(f(z),f(z_0))<\epsilon$. Here we have the Euclidean metric on $\Bbb R^2$, i.e., $d(z,z_0)=\sqrt{(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2}$ and the standard metric on $\Bbb R$, i.e., $d(f(z),f(z_0))=|x-x_0|$.
As $$\sqrt{(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2}\ge \sqrt{(x-x_0)^2}=|x-x_0|$$
we see that we can simply pick $\delta=\epsilon$.

Comment: Wow I wouldn't have thought to change the variables. But why are we using the standard metric?

Answer (score 0):

You have $$0 \le \vert x \vert \le \sqrt{x^2 +y^2}.$$ Now take $\epsilon > 0$, for $x^2 + y^2 \le \epsilon^2$ you have $0 \le \vert x \vert \le \epsilon$ allowing you to conclude that $\delta = \epsilon^2$ is convenient for the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof.

Comment: Shouldn't |x - $x_0$| be less then epsilon?

Comment: My proof is valid for continuity at $(0,0)$. If you want to prove continuity at $(x_0,y_0)$, you can replace the first inequality by $\vert x- x_0 \vert \le \sqrt{(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2}$

Comment: Oh I mean shouldn't the entire thing be strictly less than epsilon? Because if I'm less than or equal to epsilon (on the last line where you said $x^2$ + $y^2$ $\leq$ $\epsilon$